# MySQL return array when SELECT FROM row is stated

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a MySQL query that is not working and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code for selecting the id from the url and using it as a variable so Mysql can return the img_url column.

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;            
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "photos";
    $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
    $id = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
    $image = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT img_url FROM $table_name WHERE id = $id");
    echo $id
    ?>
```

and then to show my image

```
 <img src='<?php echo $image; ?>'>
```

The result I get back from MySQL is "array". I don't know if it matters but the id column is AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY. Also, I know "echo $id" does return the the id from the url so I know it works. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Its probably returning array with one row with your img url... try <img src='<?php echo $image['img_url']; ?>' > or check how $image variable is structured with print_r($image);

Comment: Try `$image = $wpdb->get_var("...")` [wpdb::get_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a single value (one column from one row) you can use [wpdb::get_var](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/)

```
$image = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT img_url FROM $table_name WHERE id = $id");
$echo $image;
```

If you use [wpdb::get_results](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) you will get an arry of rows. In this case you would need to access the value with `$image[0]['img_url']` or with `$image[0]->img_url` - depending on the fetch mode.

Since the `$id` is a user input you should also use [wpdb::prepare](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT img_url FROM $table_name WHERE id = %d", $id);
$image = $wpdb->get_var($query);
$echo $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine the exact type of a value, you can use:

```
echo var_export($value, true);
```

So in your case:

```
echo var_export($image, true);
```

With this debug line, you should see that `$image` is an array and its content.

**Update:**

> It returns `array( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'img_url' => 'wallbate.cc/image/IMG_0026.jpg';, )), )`

You probably want the image url, to do so, I think you have to do:

```
$image_url = $image[0]['img_url']
<img src='<?php echo $image_url; ?>'>
```

Comment: It returns array ( 0 => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'img_url' => 'http://wallbate.cc/image/IMG_0026.jpg', )), )